# Does the Facebook graph API have a "/me" resource?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I'm looking at the reference for the Facebook Graph API but cannot see documentation for a `/me` resource so I can get the profile of the access token I hold.

I'm looking at v5.0 but no version of the API docs discusses this resource.

This is for configuring my OAuth2 login library which is working for Google and Microsoft (which both have a `/me`) but I'm lost with Facebook.

Note - I do not wish to use the Facebook JS SDK but "normal" OAuth2 flow using browser redirects and a server-side backchannel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its just buried here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#me

> The /me node is a special endpoint that translates to the user_id of the person (or the page_id of the Facebook Page) whose access token is currently being used to make the API calls. If you had a User access token, you could retrieve all of a User's photos by using:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /me/photos
```

In the same linked doc, just below "/me", it mentions using `?fields=x,y,z` to reduce or expand the set of fields to return.